What could the material be for this tubing?

I had a supply of this tube that I love and don’t have a part number for. When I tried to reorder it (2x4mm), I assumed it was silicone, but all the silicone tubing I have is slightly different. I care about kink resistance and impermeability. Please see picture below. The tube in question has a more “blue” hue in comparison to the “white” silicone. Any ideas?
Thank you!!

vinyl tubing has the appearance of the tubing in your image

that tube is not white ... it is clear and colorless

if you do not want kinks, then insert a spring into the tubing

Look on mcmaster carr and you'll see there are a lot of clear tubes that are visually similar to what you have.
